# npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python3" in the PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

Running `npm install` in the root of my project and getting errors below. `Ubuntu22`

```
$ node -v
v19.2.0
$ npm -v
8.19.3
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

**terminal**

```
npm install
...
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/cookie/code/laravel_pusher_axios/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/cookie/code/laravel_pusher_axios/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/cookie/code/laravel_pusher_axios/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.2.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python3" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python3 /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.14.0-1054-oem
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/cookie/code/laravel_pusher_axios/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/cookie/code/laravel_pusher_axios/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/cookie/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T13_43_35_212Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm not entirely sure it is a Python issue? I have Python installed on my machine;-

```
python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Please advise? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell just by looking at your package.json file.

However, I believe that the problem is with your dev dependency.
From the error, it looks like a dependent package (most probably - axios OR laravel-mix) is using an older version that uses python2.
You can see that from the below error

```
import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

Here are a few steps that you can follow:

1 - Try clearing the npm cache using the below command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2 - Try removing the above-mentioned dev dependencies and check if that solves the problem. If it does, then you just need to find the correct version of that package that would work with your node and npm (do this if step 1 does not work).

3 - If the above does not solve your problem then try changing your node version to 16 or 18.

Comment: It turns out it was `laravel mix` which was the issue. Removing this and performing `npm install` and voilla, we have an installable set of packages. thanks